# IHM with checkbox in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to realise a GUI in java that contains columns and lines and the button "check", the goal is to check if the value of a column match with criterion. 
 the columns represents the names of a data file columns, and the lines represents criteria ( I want to list them in a properties file ). can you give me an example how I can do that.

Comment: @FastSnail "Interface Homme-Machine" in french, I think OP want to say GUI :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main GUI widget toolkits existing in the Java world:

- [AWT/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html), the old way, a pur java solution which works everywhere,
- [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm), tends to be a replacement for Swing, part of the JRE since Java7,
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), use of natives functions, so the rendering is really quicker, but it may be more complicated than the two above.

About AWT/Swing, you should start by take a look at some tutorials. Then, here is the main classes you would use:

- You need a check button: `JCheckBox`
- Colums and lines ? `JTable`, mainly because you can extend an `AbstractTableModel` and easily fit the properties file. Moreover, you can save the model thanks to an `ObjectOutputStream`: your users will be happy to be able to save their works.

Once you start coding, feel free to ask a new question about your troubles :)